# Groovy script to Grails app

Tags: grails, groovy

Well I am new to Groovy/Grails. I have written a Groovy script that uses RESTClient to make HTTP POST request to JIRA server. The POST request sends a JQL query and receives the result in JSON format. Here's the full code:

```
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient;
import groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseDecorator;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor;
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*

@Grab(value = 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.1.6', 
      initClass = false)
@Grapes([
@Grab(group = 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', 
      module = 'http-builder', version = '0.5.2'),
@GrabExclude('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy')
])

// connect to JIRA
def jiraApiUrl = 'http://my-jira.com/rest/api/2/'
def jiraClient = new RESTClient(jiraApiUrl);

// authentication
def basic = 'Basic ' + 'username:password'.bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
jiraClient.client.addRequestInterceptor (
new HttpRequestInterceptor() {
    void process(HttpRequest httpRequest, 
                 HttpContext httpContext) {
                      httpRequest.addHeader('Authorization', basic)
      }
    })

// http post method
def uriPath = 'search'
def param = [maxResults : 1, jql : '<jql-query>']

def Issues = jiraClient.post(requestContentType : JSON, path : uriPath, body : param)

def slurpedIssues = new JsonSlurper().parseText(Issues.data.toString())

println Issues.data.total
```

I need to migrate this script to a Grails app. Any suggestions as to how to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define dependencies in BuildConfig (except the groovy dependency)
2. copy script contents to a Service

Possible extension:

1. use the [grails rest plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/rest) or [grails rest-client-builder plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/rest-client-builder) instead of http-builder

Comment: Thanks for the response! Much appreciated. 

I added the dependencies and copied the script to a **Controller**. When I access the controller from the web browser, it gives me a NullPointerException.
"Message:Cannot invoke method post() on null object"

The same happened in a Service. Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like `jiraClient` is null.  Worth checking if you initialised it properly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! There was a problem with the initialization. But getting a new NullPointerException now. Sigh! Same line, `def Issues = jiraClient.post(requestContentType : JSON, path : uriPath, body : param)`. "Message: null".

Comment: is `JSON` a class, or should it be a String (i.e. `'JSON'`)?

Comment: Few error were there, rectified it. Thanks! I am unable to edit the `contentType` which gives me a `Unsupported Media Type` exception.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the logic into Service object will give you the ability to do dependency injection, which is native to grails services.

Also, you should consider using `AsyncHTTPBuilder` if your app has many users trying to make requests.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe that the service response will be directly rendered to JSON

```
  //your controller 
    class AbcController{

    //your action   
    def save() {
    render(abcService.save(params) as JSON)//your service response now been rendered to JSON
        }

    }

//your service class    class AbcService {
    def save(params){
     ....
     return something
    }
}
```